# Powershell test multiple computer multiple conditions

Tags: powershell

I'm wanting to test multiple conditions on a list of multiple computers.

I have a file: computers.txt that contains:

```
Computer1
Computer2
Computer3
Computer4
```

What I want is an output file that looks like this:

```
COMPUTER  AD-COMPUTER_OBJECT  PING   abc.com    xyz.com
Computer1 True                True   A Record   NULL
Computer2 True                True   NULL       CNAME Record
Computer3 False               True   A Record   NULL
Computer4 False               False  NULL       NULL
```

Where AD-COMPUTER_OBJECT tests using get-adcomputer to see if there is a computer object in AD, PING tests using test-connection to see if the computer responds to ping, abc.com queries the abc.com zone nslookup style, and xyz.com queries the xyz.com nslookup style.

The purpose is to determine not only if the computer is active, but also if there are stale computer objects or dns records for inactive computers.

I know how to test these conditions individually using a get-content foreach-object loop - but I'd really like to check for all the conditions and export them spreadsheet style (I displayed it tab delimited but export-csv is fine)

Comment: You dont have problems with your code. So we cant help you. If you search someone who write you a script hire a programmer.

Comment: I believe he knows how to write the basic import and test functions but he does not know how to export the results in the desired format, i'll write something up, @davehahn could you add some of the existing coding to this question and show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired format you could use select-object this allows you to define your own columns and export it to csv for example.

```
function test-condition {
    return 'condition-value'
}


$Computerlist = @("pc1", "pc2", "pc3")
$Results = @()

Foreach ($Computer in $Computerlist)
{

    $con1 = test-condition
    $con2 = test-condition
    $con3 = test-condition
    $con4 = test-condition


    $Results += $Computer | Select @{N='COMPUTER'; E={$_}}, @{N="Condition 1"; E={$con1}}, @{N="Condition 2"; E={$con2}}, @{N="Condition 3"; E={$con3}}, @{N="Condition 4"; E={$con4}}

}

#In the NL Excel expects the delimiter to be ';'.
$Results | export-csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\results.csv"

#Format-Table works to
$Results | Format-Table
```

Format-Table output:

```
COMPUTER                  Condition 1               Condition 2              Condition 3              Condition 4             
--------                  -----------               -----------              -----------              -----------             
pc1                       condition-value           condition-value          condition-value          condition-value         
pc2                       condition-value           condition-value          condition-value          condition-value         
pc3                       condition-value           condition-value          condition-value          condition-value
```